# Group By Sql Query. How could I create?

Tags: sql

I have this query :

```
select AlarmGroup,AgentName from v_Dashboard_Alarms;
```

when I execute it I have this list

```
AlarmGroup     AgentName
==========     ==========
GroupName        Thassos
GroupName        Thassos
GroupName        Thassos
NULL             Pythion
NULL             Metaxas
NULL             Metaxas
GroupName        Pilio
GroupName        Pilio
```

I want to write a query Group By AgentName if AlarmGroup != Null
I want to take this list

```
AlarmGroup     AgentName
==========     ==========
GroupName        Thassos
NULL             Pythion
NULL             Metaxas
NULL             Metaxas
GroupName        Pilio
```

How can i solve?
Thanks!!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT where not null UNION ALL SELECT where null

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What is the logic to return `Metaxas` twice?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try following query:

```
Select Distinct AlarmGroup, AgentName
from table
where AlarmGroup is null 
UNION ALL 
Select AlarmGroup, AgentName
from table
where AlarmGroup,AgentName is not null
group by AlarmGroup
```

Comment: The second query is invalid SQL. You can't use `group by AlarmGroup` without applying an aggregate function to `agentname`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Edited the answer. It might have worked in mysql but again its not a good practice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In ANSI SQL, you can do:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by alarmgroup) as seqnum
      from v_Dashboard_Alarms  t
     )
select alarmgroup, agentname
from t
group by (case when alarmgroup is null then seqnum end),
         alarmgroup, agentname;
```

The purpose of `row_number()` is to assign a different value to each row.  If you already have a unique id, use that instead.  The `group by` then breaks out the expanded group based on what seems to be the obvious logic.

You can also do this with `union all`:

```
select alarmgroup, agentname
from v_Dashboard_Alarms t
where alarmgroup is null
union all
select distinct alarmgroup, agentname
from v_Dashboard_Alarms t
where alarmgroup is not null;
```

The advantage of the first query is that it evaluates the view only once.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thank you very much !!